# Automatisation, Load .prg file, run it with pre-defined variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, visual-foxpro

The idea is  that in one folder there are two files

```
test.csv
test.prg
```

I would like to run with .bat file (or .vbs) the file test.prg with variable "2510".

It will automatically load in Visual Fox Pro (here I do not know how to run script automatically with out physically click the exclamation mark) and visual fox pro should use variable from .bat/.vbs file as 2510.

```
1) Open test.prg
2) Load VFP
3) Use pre defined variable from .bat/.vbs
4) Run script (automatically)
5) close VFP
```

Because this is daily jobs, and I'm trying to simplify as much as possible (currently I know only how to simplify by using cmd/.bat and vbs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to run a prg file with changing parameters and you want to change the parameter in the calling .bat or .vbs file. If it is what you wanted to do, then you could simply have the bat file content like:

```
cd "c:\My Folder"
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Foxpro 9\vfp9.exe" test.prg 2510
```

and your prg would be run with that parameter. Keep in mind that parameters passed from command line is always of character data type.

However, there is an easier way. The way you do it, you would edit the .BAT file, save it and then doubleclick to execute. You might create a VFP executable instead, in command window (assuming test.prg is in c:\My Folder'):

```
set default to ('c:\My Folder')
build project MyTest from 'test.prg'
build exe MyTest from 'MyTest.pjx'
```

and you would have MyTest.exe in that folder. Your BAT file content would then be:

```
cd "c:\My Folder"
MyTest 2510
```

It is still to cumbersome. You need to edit the .BAT file, change parameter, save and doubleclick it. Make it much simpler:

In your test.prg, instead of getting a parameter from command line, ask the parameter value and do the process! That totally removes the need for a BAT file. Then you simply create a shortcut on your desktop. Whenever you doubleclick that shortcut, it would ask for the parameter and then do processing with that parameter value and quit. The content of such a test.prg would look like:

```
_screen.Visible = .T.
LOCAL cInput
cInput = INPUTBOX("What is parameter value?", "Get parameter value", "2510", 5000, '', 'Cancelled')

DO case
 CASE m.cInput == ''
   ? 'Input timed out'
 CASE m.cInput == 'Cancelled'
   ? 'Cancelled'
 CASE m.cInput == '0' Or VAL(m.cInput) != 0
   Process( VAL(m.cInput) )
 OTHERWISE
   ? 'Parameter is not numeric'  
ENDCASE

QUIT


PROCEDURE Process(tnparameter)
 ? 'Processing with parameter =', m.tnParameter
Endproc
```

Also, instead of an inputbox() which returns a character value as command line parameters do, you might get the value(s) via a form with their intended types (ie: A datetimepicker on a form getting date).

Answer (score 1):

It is really unclear what you are trying to do.  However, from VFP, I created a simple project and program that might help you.

Start VFP.  In the command window type
create project MyTest [enter]

click on the Code tab and then click new.  Paste the following code snippet

```
LPARAMETERS DOSParm1, DOSParm2, DOSParm3, DOSParm4

MESSAGEBOX( "Parm1: " + TRANSFORM( DOSParm1 ) + CHR(13)+CHR(10);
            + "Parm2: " + TRANSFORM( DOSParm2 ) + CHR(13)+CHR(10);
            + "Parm3: " + TRANSFORM( DOSParm3 ) + CHR(13)+CHR(10);
            + "Parm4: " + TRANSFORM( DOSParm4 ) + CHR(13)+CHR(10) )

RETURN
```

Save the program as MyTest.prg, then click on build for the project to create an executable.  Now you have a simple EXE file that accepts up to 4 parameters from the dos command or other methods (vbs).  You can change the actual VFP to act on whatever variables you need, but I just have them as messagebox output display.  If no parameters are provided, the default values would be logical .F. (false)

To test from a DOS prompt, you can do something like

```
MyTest oneParm anotherParm 3rd last
```

and you will get the message box displaying these 4 parameter strings.

If you skip parameters, no problem.

```
MyTest Only TwoParms
```

Again, the code can be changed to do whatever you need with your "2510" variable reference and act accordingly.